# Problemas con 'space_to_depth' en tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

Tengo el siguiente problema con notebook de python. Estoy probando una version de yolo v2 en el siguiente codigo:

```
object_detection = ObjectDectection(n_classes, IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, BOX, ARQUITECTURE='YOLO_V2')
```

Y tengo el siguiente error:

```
 object_detection = ObjectDectection(n_classes, IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, BOX, ARQUITECTURE='YOLO_V2')
    model = object_detection.model

    /content/Object_Detection.py in space_to_depth_x2(x)
     35 
     36 def space_to_depth_x2(x):
---> 37     return tf.nn.space_to_depth(x, block_size=2)
     38 
     39 def YOLO_V2_model(IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, NUMBER_OF_BBOXES, GAP=False):

module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'space_to_depth'
```

Tengo versión de tensor Flow 2.6.0 y de keras 2.6.0
Intente con cambiar dichas versiones a tensor Flow 1.14 y keras 2.3.1 y sigo con el mismo error.
Probé cambiar tensorflow.nn.space_to_depth pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Cualquier ayuda desde ya muchas gracias
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. El error

El error es claro, te dice que el módulo `tensorflow` no tiene la función que estás llamando, es decir, no existe.

Por tanto o tienes un problema con tu versión de `Tensorflow` o en la sintaxis.

### 2. Solución

Es un error puramente de `Tensorflow, ya que no estás utilizando el módulo de` Keras`y la función en`Tensorflow` depende de la versión, se encuentra en diferentes archivos, por lo que la tienes que llamar de distinta forma:

- `Tensorflow 1.X`: `tf.space_to_depth()`
- `Tensorflow 2.X`: `tf.nn.space_to_depth`

### Bonus

Los casos anteriores te debería funcionar, otros posibles errores son:

- Estás utilizando un entorno virtual y no tienes la versión de `Tensorflow` que crees tener. Para saber la versión, puedes utilizar un debugger o dentro del propio archivo que estás ejecutando poner `print(tensorflow.__version__)`. `__version__` es un atributo que tienen todos los paquetes de Python.
- La instalación ha sido incorrecta y tienes que reinstalarlo.